# How do I create Modality Worklist for a patient in DCM4CHE using HL7 message?

Tags: dicom, hl7, dcm4che

I have managed to create Patients in DCM4CHEE using HL7 messages. I have also created Studies, Series and Observation Reports for respective Patients using only HL7 messages. But I am stuck at Modality Worklist. I cannot find sample HL7 messages to create MWLs. Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out.

I basically used this `ER7` sample message to create a patient along with a Modality Worklist in my DCM4CHEE:

```
MSH|^~\&|HMIS|DUHS|PACS||20181016115248||OMI^O23^OMI_O23|20181016115248|P|2.5.1||||||UNICODE UTF-8
PID|||18131495254749211102 71^^^FR&UNKNOWN&ISO^NH~DDS-30938^^^DDS&1.3.6.1.4.1.12559.11.1.4.1.2&ISO^PI||Isidor^Raphaël||19281231201400|M|||
ORC|NW|12028^IHE_OM_OP^1.3.6.1.4.1.12559.11.1.2.2.4.2^ISO|12841^IHE_OM_OF^1.3.6.1.4.1.12559.11.1.2.2.4.3^ISO||SC||||||||||||
OBR|1|12028^IHE_OM_OP^1.3.6.1.4.1.12559.11.1.2.2.4.2^ISO||MAWF0017^Breast Specimen Mammography, left^99IHE^9MAWF0017^MG: Breast specimen, left^99IHE|||||||||||||||OMRP1345|OMSPS1372||||CT||||||||||||||||||||MAWF0017^Brest Specimen Mammography, left^IHE99
```

The key was to use `OMI^O23^OMI_O23` as the trigger event and providing Modality at `OBR-24`, and (for some reason) not leaving `OBR-19` and `OBR-20` empty.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about your exact workflow and I do not know DCM4CHEE. I am answering in terms of HL7 only.

ORM (Order Entry) message is generally good candidate to process Orders. The Order is then converted to Modality Worklist Item. I do not know if this works with DCM4CHEE though.

Following is general template of `ORM` message `O01` event:

```
MSH|^~\&|HIS_APP|HIS_FACILITY|PACS_APP|PACS_FACILITY|20130614131415||ORM^O01|MsgCtrlId_ORM|P|2.3
PID|1||PatientID||Patient Name||20000514|F||||||||||AdmID
PV1|1|OP||||||^Ref Phy||||||||||||50
ORC|NW|||||||||||^Req Phy|||||^Institution Name
OBR|1|ACC.NO.01||SPSID^SPSDesc|ROUTINE||||||||||RPDesc|||SSName|RPID|SPSLocation|SSAETitle|||CT|||||||Reason For Proc|||SchPerPhyName||20130614132030
ZDS|StudyIUID
```

This is from 2.3 version; you are using 2.5.1. All 2.x versions are backward compatible; so I hope that should not be an issue.

Note the `ZDS` segment which also accepts Study Instance UID.

Following links may be helpful:

https://datica.com/academy/hl7-203-the-hl7-orm-order-entry-message/
https://corepointhealth.com/resource-center/hl7-resources/hl7-orm-message/